# UWP - StateTrigger in ListView.ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, visualstatemanager

I'm having trouble adding `ColorAnimation` to `VisualStateManager` on my ListView `ItemTemplate`. The VisualStateManager doesn't seem to change its visual states.

What I'm trying to do here is start a `StoryBoard` that would start to smoothly change the `Rectangle.Fill` color on the `ListViewItem`, as soon as its underlying viewmodel's IsReady property value changes.

*What am I doing wrong? And how to do this correctly (preferably without the pointless UserControl)?*

**Here's the XAML:**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyList}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:B">
                    <UserControl>
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="group">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="state1">
                                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                            <StateTrigger IsActive="{x:Bind IsReady, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:1.8" To="Red" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rect" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="Blue" Width="20" Height="20" />
                        </Grid>
                    </UserControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Test</Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Here's the code behind:**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App1
{
    public abstract class NotifyPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected NotifyPropertyChangedBase()
        {
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class B : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
    {
        private bool isReady;
        public bool IsReady
        {
            get { return isReady; }
            set { if (isReady != value) { isReady = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); } }
        }
    }

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public ObservableCollection<B> MyList { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<B>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                MyList.Add(new B());
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyList[2].IsReady = !MyList[2].IsReady;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? I tested with your code and it works well in my side.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT, without using that `UserControl`, I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` in Set_Windows_UI_Xaml_StateTrigger_IsActive in MainPage.g.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a `UserControl` is needed. Without it, we may get error as you've seen. To manage visual states, we need a [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.window#Windows_UI_Xaml_Window_Content) subclass, however, [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid) is not a [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.window#Windows_UI_Xaml_Window_Content) subclass, it inherits from [Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.panel).

> Visual states are sometimes useful for scenarios where you want to change the state of some area of UI that's not immediately a [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control) subclass. You can't do this directly because the *control* parameter of the [GoToState(Control, String, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager#Windows_UI_Xaml_VisualStateManager_GoToState_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_System_String_System_Boolean_) method requires a [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control) subclass, which refers to the object that the VisualStateManager acts upon.
>
> We recommend you define a custom [UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol) to either be the [Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.window#Windows_UI_Xaml_Window_Content) root or be a container for other content you want to apply states to (such as a [Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.panel)). Then you can call [GoToState(Control, String, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager#Windows_UI_Xaml_VisualStateManager_GoToState_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_System_String_System_Boolean_) on your [UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol) and apply states regardless of whether the rest of the content is a [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control).

For more info, please see **Visual states for elements that aren't controls** under [**Remarks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager#remarks) of [VisualStateManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager).